# Java's logic concerning methods that return values and their parameters

Tags: java, methods

Java methods don't require return statements to match their parameters. Why?

Consider this trivial method that takes three parameters, x, y and z. The method works when only one return parameter is used (i.e. return x, y, or z). Why wouldn't Java require `return x, y, z;` or something like that? I'm a Java beginner so maybe I'll learn why when we get to OOP principles. Anyway, I'm curious if there is a logic behind it or that's just Java. Thanks.

```
public static int someNumbers(int x, int y, int z) {

    if (y > z) {
       System.out.printf("%d is greater than %d", y, z);
    } else {
       System.out.printf("Number three is %d", z);
    }   
    return x;   
}
```

Comment: The parameters are what you put in to a method, the return value is what you get out. Why should they match?

Comment: I would also say that traditionally, most programming languages return only a single result, and Java was very much in the mold of a traditional language when it was designed.

Comment: By that logic should a method that takes no parameters be forced to have void return then? That'd be baad.

Comment: When you need to return more than one value, you create an instance of a Java object class that holds all the values you want to return.  One return value that holds many values.

Comment: @PaulBoddington What puzzles me is 'return x;' or 'return y;' or even arithmetic nonsense like 'return y * y % z + y - z * z;' all work. Is the rule that as long as one of the parameter variables is in the return statement, it will return correctly?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc thanks, that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Parameters` and `Return types` don't really have any relation to each other. A method may have 0 or more parameters of any arbitrary type.

```
public int someMethod(int x, String y, Object z) {
   //Does something
    return x * 5 - 10;
}
```

But it may only have 0 or 1 return values. Where 0 return values must be defined as void:

```
public void someMethod(int x, String y, Object z) {
   //Does something but returns nothing
}
```

When needing to return more than 1 value, such as 2 `Integers`, you could create an `Object` holding these values. This is kinda what defines `Java` as an `Object Oriented Language`.

```
class IntegerHolder{
    int firstValue;
    int secondValue;

    //This is a constructor, it creates the object.
    public IntegerHolder(int first, int second){
        firstValue = first;
        secondValue = second;
    }
}

public IntegerHolder someMethod(int x, String y, Object z) {
    return new IntegerHolder(x, x * 2);
}
```

I do advise to read up on some basic `Java` however. There are hundreds of resources around the web.

Answer (score 1):

A well defined function can have only one output. It is a such a relationship between input and output that you can give multiple input but it will give only one output.

Java function definition just follow this rule.You can use some other features of java in order to get more than one result at a time. But should return on output as per the definition of function.You can also read this:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271613/why-is-a-function-defined-as-having-only-one-y-value-output